# How to populate a DataGridView based on Excel search results and remove blank headers from the DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have 1 Form with 1 TextBox where an user will type `ProductId(FCID)`, press the enter key and, based on that, I want to populate my DataGridView with the results of a search.

There are 2 problems here:

- How do I filter records from Excel based on user entered `FCID`?
- While binding the DataSource from Excel, how to remove blank records as shown in the second image?

[image]

[image]

Code:

```
private void txtProductId_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        string pathName = txtFilePath.Text;
        string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(txtFilePath.Text);
        DataTable tbContainer = new DataTable();
        string strConn = string.Empty;
        string sheetName = fileName;

        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(pathName);
        if (!file.Exists) { throw new Exception("Error, file doesn't exists!"); }
        string extension = file.Extension;

        switch (extension)
        {
            case ".xls":
                strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + pathName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;'";
                break;
            case ".xlsx":
                strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + pathName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;'";
                break;
            default:
                strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + pathName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;'";
                break;
        }
        OleDbConnection cnnxls = new OleDbConnection(strConn);
        OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter(string.Format("select * from [{0}$]", sheetName), cnnxls);
        oda.Fill(tbContainer);
        grdProductList.DataSource = tbContainer;
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

I have not worked previously on Windows Forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a Range of cells that contain the Data you want to retrieve. In the form:

```
[sheet1$[Start Cell]:[End Cell]]
```

In your case, you can change the query, including only the Cells from `B6` to `ZZ` (which seems to be the range that contains your Data. Adapt it as needed):
Remember to Dispose of the disposable objects you created or declare them in `using` blocks)

```
string sheetName = "Sheet1";
string query = $"SELECT * FROM [{sheetName}$B6:ZZ]"
OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, cnnxls); 
//(...)
oda.Dispose();
```

You can of course specify a Filter:

```
int fieldID = 204;
//
string query = $"SELECT * FROM [{sheetName}$B6:ZZ] WHERE FCID = {fieldID}"

using (OleDbConnection cnnxls = new OleDbConnection(strConn))
using (OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, cnnxls))
{
    oda.Fill(tbContainer);
    grdProductList.DataSource = tbContainer;
}
```

or a Range filter:

```
string query = $"SELECT * FROM [{sheetName}$B6:ZZ] WHERE FCID BETWEEN 204 AND 300"
```

or, using variable values:

```
int minValue = 204;
int maxValue = 300;
string query = $"SELECT * FROM [{sheetName}$B6:ZZ] WHERE FCID BETWEEN {minValue} AND {maxValue}"
```

The `.xls` format doesn't support a generic Range:

**`[sheet1$B6:ZZ]`** will not be accepted.
**`[sheet1$B6:O65535]`** is accepted: the data is in the columns range `B6:O*`.

**UPDATE**: (specific to this question):

Given the composition of the Excel Sheet, the Field Names need to be specified explicitly, otherwise the resulting `DataTable` will contain empty columns:

```
int fieldID = 204;    
string fieldSelector = "[ FCID], [Product Name], [Category], [Sub Category], " +
                       "[Brand], [MRP], [Disc %], [Stock], [Discount Type]";

query = $"SELECT {fieldSelector} FROM [{sheetName}$B6:O65535] WHERE [ FCID] = {fieldID}";
```

Comment: Is it possible to parametrize WHERE FCID = '204'" part?

Comment: Yes, of course, the same way `{sheetName}` is a parameter. So, something like: `WHERE FCID = '{SomeVariable}'`. This is using interpolated strings (`$`). You can also use `string.Format` almost exactly the same way.

Comment: I am getting this error : 'The Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the object 'rptDiscountReport$B6:ZZ'.  Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly.'

Comment: But i am using excel 2010 and how do i support search for xls?

Comment: Excel 2010 supports `.xlsx` format (from 2007), I don't know why you're mentioning it. About the legacy `.xls`, I'm not sure. I'll give it a look. Note that you can use `ACE.OLEDB.12.0` (or `16`), to open a `.xls` file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190299/discussion-between-learning-overthinker-confused-and-jimi).

Comment: See the Update part. Use a field selector to extract the non-empty columns.

Comment: Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me and for your valuable time.Appreciated :)

Comment: Well, thanks. But, did you get it to work? I've tested your WorkSheet. With the query string you can see in the Update, it's working without problems on my side. Both formats, no empty columns.