# .xls importing to datatable missing some fields

Tags: c#, oledb

I am using OLEDB connection to mport data from .xls to datatable.
my code is

```
public static DataTable getXlssheetstoDatatable(string ExcelFilePath)
{
    string query = "select * from ["Test$"]";
    try
    {
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection MyConnection;
        System.Data.DataSet DtSet;
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter MyCommand;
        MyConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + ExcelFilePath + @";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;IMEX=1;TypeGuessRows=0;ImportMixedTypes=Text""");

        //MyConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + ExcelFilePath + @";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;IMEX=1;TypeGuessRows=0;ImportMixedTypes=Text""");
        MyCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(query, MyConnection);
        MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", "dtHeader");
        DtSet = new System.Data.DataSet();
        MyCommand.Fill(DtSet);

        DataTable dt = DtSet.Tables[0];
        MyConnection.Close();
        return dt;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return new DataTable();
    }

    return new DataTable();
}
```

xls with following data will work fine:

```
Col1    Col2        Col3    Col4    Col5    Col6    Col7        Col8    Col9
HD      HD123456    1234    xyz     95              58.5 X 91   16   
        123457      1235    abc     90              65           3   
        123458      1236    mnb     90              78           1   
        123489      1237    xyz     54              48           1.85
```

with any number of rows above excel data is working fine.
But in the following case it is not working:

```
Col1    Col2        Col3    Col4    Col5    Col6    Col7        Col8    Col9
        123457      1235    abc     90               65          3   
        123458      1236    mnb     90               78          1   
        123489      1237    xyz     54               48          1.85
        123457      1235    abc     90               65          3   
        123458      1236    mnb     90               78          1   
        123489      1237    xyz     54               48          1.85
        123457      1235    abc     90               65          3   
        123458      1236    mnb     90               78          1   
        123489      1237    xyz     54               48          1.85
        123457      1235    abc     90               65          3   
        123458      1236    mnb     90               78          1   
        123489      1237    xyz     54               48          1.85
        123457      1235    abc     90               65          3   
        123458      1236    mnb     90               78          1   
        123489      1237    xyz     54               48          1.85
        123457      1235    abc     90               65          3   
        123458      1236    mnb     90               78          1   
        123489      1237    xyz     54               48          1.85
        123457      1235    abc     90               65          3   
        123458      1236    mnb     90               78          1   
        123489      1237    xyz     54               48          1.85
HD      HD123456    1234    xyz     95               58.5 X 91   16
```

Comment: Can you format your data a bit better? [Here an online tool to help you](https://senseful.github.io/text-table/)

Comment: Use the `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` provider. You can select a range of Cells: `string sheetName = "Test"; string query = "SELECT * FROM [{sheetName}$A1:I22]"` -- (or `"SELECT * FROM [{sheetName}$A1:I65535]"`). See also the notes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55240079/7444103)

Comment: (unrelated) You need to `Dispose()` (or declare with `using` statements) the DataAdapter, the DataSet and the Connection (calling `.Close()` on does it, but you should follow the disposable pattern) -- Since you don't need a DataSet but a DataTable, create and `Fill()` one instead of a DataSet -- the last `return new DataTable();` is out of scope (unreachable code) -- this: `"select * from ["Test$"]";` is wrong.

Comment: The jet (and ACE) engine doesn't like the empty data in column 1.  Seen issue before.  It seems the jet uses the first column as a row header.  try add HDR=Yes to the connection string and see if that helps.

Comment: in the first file mixed type column appeared in the top. where in second excel mixed type column appreared in the end. so mixed type data is missing in datatable

Comment: With `IMEX=1`, all data types are treated as text, so the problem is another. Probably because the first column is empty, so you need to explicitly specify a range of Cells (as already mentioned).

Comment: I checked with adding something on first column. but the result is same.