# OledDBConnection closes and reset data read object to first value in excel

Tags: c#

I am currently using functions in which I create connection and then get half of excel data and pass it to other function, but the problem is when I recall the function it starts reading the excel from start again. Following is my code Structure:

```
    Public static int Get_Data()
       {
        command = new OleDbCommand("select * from [" + fileName + "]", connection);
        using (connection = new OleDbConnection(con))
        {
            connection.Open();

            using (dr = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    var col_names = dr[0];
                    var data = dr[1];
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void Excel_Connection()
    {
        String path2 = @"";
        con = $@"";

        var file = Directory.GetFiles(path2).FirstOrDefault();

        if (file != null)
        {
            fileName = Path.GetFileName(file);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No File Found in the following Path = " + path2);
            fileName = "";
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
    }
   public static void Table_Creation(String[] columnNames, String[] Job_data, String[] sample)
    {
     Excel_Connection();
     Get_Data();
    }
   public static void Second_Call()
    {
     Get_Data();
    }
```

Now as you can see I have called Get_Data function twice from 2 different functions, it resets my data reader and start reading from start of the excel, where as I want to start reading again from where I left.

Can you please advise ?

I have tried to explain better. Thanks

Comment: See the notes and sample code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55240079/7444103) (the selection range, specifically)

Comment: Well, you obviously start reading from scratch. With 'using' you are disposing both reader and connection, so each time you call GetData you start all over. And what do you mean by "where I left". You are reading the file till the end.

If you want just a half - you can use some where clause in the query and a parameter for GetData function to control that where close

Comment: I have a condition that IF array = "My_String" then stop reading and send array to function so that writes and then when I call this GetData function to read what is after "My_String" it starts reading from scratch, how can I fix this ? is there a way that connection stays open and data reader keeps pointing to the cell from where I left ?

Answer (score 0):

I would rethink the application logic to avoid doing that. 
Try building selects so that you get all the data you need at the moment and nothing else.

But if you really need your implementation...
You'll have to have some globals - the connection and the DataReader. 
Open connection once (without USING, as once you leave using block - connection is disposed), pass it to the code creating and opening the DataReader(again global, again without USING) and then use that  DataReader. 
If you stop reading it, do whatever you need to  and then continue reading - it will go from the last read record as DataReader is forward-only. 
Remember to properly close and dispose your DataReader and Connection manually.

But once again this is smelly )