# how to read excel column names with special characters with visual studio and oracle

Tags: excel, oracle, vb.net, winforms, oledb

Good night friends,

I am uploading an excel to oracle and I found that some columns of the excel have special characters in the name of the column, these are:

"FECHA/CONV" AND "N°CODIGO"

If I remove the special characters it works fine, but I can't edit the excel file, I just have to read it,

how can I do so that visual does not generate an error in the mappeo and in the select to the excel sheet.

I will appreciate any help.

The exact error I have is:
no values ​​have been set for some of the set parameters.

Thanks,

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
            Dim _connString As String = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.10.100.1)(PORT = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVICE_NAME = ORACLE))); User Id=USER; password=PASS;"
        Dim rutacarpeta As String
        Dim NombreArchivo As String
        Dim tablaBBDD As String
        'Dim ot As OracleTransaction = conn.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted)
        Using conn As OracleConnection = New OracleConnection(_connString)
            conn.Open()
            Dim ot As OracleTransaction = conn.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted)
            Try

                rutacarpeta = "C:\2021\"
                NombreArchivo = "FILE_0.xlsx"
                tablaBBDD = "FILE_TEST"
                Dim xlsxConn As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;';"
                xlsxConn = String.Format(xlsxConn, rutacarpeta + NombreArchivo).Trim()

                Using excel_con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(xlsxConn)
                    excel_con.Open()
                    'Dim hoja As String = excel_con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, Nothing).Rows(0)()
                    Dim command As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT FECHA/CONV,CODIGO,ACUERDO FROM [FILE$]", excel_con)

                    Dim dr As OleDbDataReader
                    dr = command.ExecuteReader()

                    Using bulkCopy As OracleBulkCopy = New OracleBulkCopy(conn)
                        bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 90000
                        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = tablaBBDD
                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(New OracleBulkCopyColumnMapping("FECHA/CONV", "FECHA"))
                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(New OracleBulkCopyColumnMapping("N°CODIGO", "CODIGO"))
                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(New OracleBulkCopyColumnMapping("ACUERDO", "ACUERDO"))
                        bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dr)
                        ot.Commit()

                        bulkCopy.Close()
                    End Using
                End Using

            Catch ex As Exception
                Try
                    ot.Rollback()
                Catch ex1 As Exception
                    MessageBox.Show(ex1.Message)
                End Try

                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

            End Try
        End Using
    End Sub
```

Comment: `SELECT [Whatever]` Does that work?

Comment: [How to populate a DataGridView based on Excel search results and remove blank headers from the DataGridView?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55240079/7444103)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably kick yourself when I point out that you've quoted the table name, because it contains a special character, and that works.. you've just forgotten to quote the column names

```
SELECT [FECHA/CONV],[CODIGO],[ACUERDO] FROM [FILE$]
```

They don't all need quoting but it won't hurt. Also if you get any errors on the oracle side when you set up your bulk copy column mapping, perhaps consider aliasing the excel names to something simpler, and using that

```
SELECT [FECHA/CONV] as A,CODIGO,ACUERDO FROM [FILE$]

...

...Add(New OracleBulkCopyColumnMapping("A", "FECHA"))
```